# Macro constants concatenation using ##

Tags: c, macros, header-files, libraries

I'm writing some libraries for a microcontroller, and for that purpose, I use macro-like functions. For example, a macro-like function to enable an I2C module is defined as:

```
#define I2C_MODULE_ENABLE(_x) \
    I2C##_x##CONLbits.I2CEN = 1
```

where `_x` is the module number (e.g.,`1` or `2` in my case).

If a user calls this macro-like function as `I2C_MODULE_ENABLE(1)`, it would be expanded by a preprocessor as `I2C1CONLbits. I2CEN = 1`.

However, if a user calls this macro-like function as `I2C_MODULE_ENABLE(MY_I2C)`, where `MY_I2C` is a macro constant defined in a user-defined `config.h` file that is included by my `i2c.h` library (e.g., the macro constant is defined as `#define MY_I2C 1`), the macro-like function would be expanded as `I2CMY_I2CCONLbits. I2CEN = 1`.

I know that I need to somehow evaluate the `MY_I2C` macro constant before concatenation, and I can do that by adding another macro level:

```
#define __I2CxCONLbits(_x) I2C##_x##CONLbits
#define I2C_MODULE_ENABLE(_x) \
    __I2CxCONLbits.I2CEN = 1
```

My question is: **is there a more elegant solution to this problem** since I have multiple registers like the `CONLbits` register. Using this approach I would need to define a special `__I2CxREGISTER(_x)` macro for every register.

I tried to do something like this:

```
#define __I2Cx(_x) I2C##_x
#define I2C_MODULE_ENABLE(_x) \
    __I2Cx(_x)##CONLbits.I2CEN = 1
```

but that produces an output like this: `I2C1 CONLbits .I2CEN = 1`, and my compiler is complaining about the whitespace between `I2C1` and `CONLbits` tokens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't adding the macro level properly, as I see it. The usual idiom is to define a wrapper that does nothing but forward the argument. That way, if the argument is itself a macro, it will be expanded before being passed to the macro that is wrapped:

```
#define I2C_MODULE_ENABLE__(x_) \
    I2C##x_##CONLbits.I2CEN = 1

#define I2C_MODULE_ENABLE(x_) \
    I2C_MODULE_ENABLE__(x_)
```

I took the liberty of renaming your macro parameter, since identifiers with leading underscores are defined as reserved for the implementation, I think it's better to be safe than sorry.

---

To solve your problem of the space I'd go with the proverbial level of indirection, and use a function like macro to generate the correct prefix token, and pass it along two levels to make sure it's expanded correctly:

```
#define I2Cx__(x_) I2C##x_
#define I2C_MODULE_ENABLE__(IC_) \
    IC_##CONLbits.I2CEN = 1
#define I2C_MODULE_ENABLE_(IC_) \
    I2C_MODULE_ENABLE__(IC_)
#define I2C_MODULE_ENABLE(x_) \
    I2C_MODULE_ENABLE_(I2Cx__(x_))
```

See it live [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f560bc610db8fc21)

The whole shtick is to make sure the preprocessor sees and produces valid tokens at each step. Which can be a bit tiresome.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem / answer the question.

Comment: @melpomene - I got there eventually. Had trouble verifying the code sample on my favorite cloud compiler :)

Comment: @melpomene - So did the OP's attempt. Why do you think it shouldn't?

Comment: "My question is: **is there a more elegant solution to this problem** since I have multiple registers like the `CONLbits` register. Using this approach I would need to define a special `__I2CxREGISTER(_x)` macro for every register."

Comment: @melpomene - which was followed by the erronous attempt that I tweaked to give a valid token. But this is moot, keep your downvote if you see fit.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you for your answer. Back to the naming convention, thank you for your suggestion not to use leading underscores, I wasn't aware this was reserved. I don't like the solution with trailing underscores, as IDEs usually offer autocomplete, and an user would be offered with two (or more) macros, e.g., `I2C_MODULE_ENABLE` and `I2C_MODULE_ENABLE_`.

Comment: @MarkoGulin - You can of course choose any convention which works best. Changing the position of the underscores was just the simplest to do for an SO post.

Comment: @StoryTeller Can I start a macro (constant or function) with a $ character? I found that compilers support this, but would it be a "bad practice" just like starting with underscores?

Comment: @MarkoGulin - The C standard doesn't allow it, although some compilers allow it for certain target architectures. I would also like to say *can* technically use leading underscores, just be careful to not run afoul the rules (as they are defined in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/decl/namespace.html) for instnace). My blanket warning was because I feel it's not worth fussing about, just avoid those names. But if you are really feel nothing else works for you, just try to adhere to the guidelines in the FAQ.